# invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''/ connecting with SqlAlchemy + firebird

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, firebird2.5

I'm learning python with the pyramid framework and sqlalchemy ORM. I'm working with firebird database and wanted to retrieve data from my database. I've had this error :

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

on that part of code :

```
engine = create_engine('firebird+fdb://SYSDBA:d66cbc9b@localhost:/home/viktor/BDD/siteweb.fdb', echo=True)
s = text("select * from tusers")
k = engine.execute(s).fetchall()
```

My table SQL code is :

```
CREATE TABLE TUSERS(
  ID integer NOT NULL,
  EMAIL varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "PASSWORD" varchar(50),
  CONSTRAINT INTEG_9 PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT INTEG_10 UNIQUE (EMAIL)
);
```

and :

```
INSERT INTO TUSERS (EMAIL, PASSWORD)
VALUES (
    'rus.grechka@gmail.com', 
    'my_password'
);
```

Maybe the problem comed from the trigger (beacause you need to create a trigger that increments the id value(there's not auto-increment property)) ?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the complete error message (and the traceback).

Answer (score 2):

The [connection URL format](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/firebird.html) of SQL Alchemy for Firebird is:

```
firebird+fdb://user:password@host:port/path/to/db[?key=value&key=value...]
```

In your url you have no value for port, which causes the conversion error as you have an empty string for port.

You can fix this by specifying the port number of your Firebird server (default 3050):

```
firebird+fdb://SYSDBA:d66cbc9b@localhost:3050/home/viktor/BDD/siteweb.fdb
```

or without colon as - contrary to the documentation - the [port is optional](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/9a3c9ba7beb18dfd6232deb895528ea8593a12b0/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#url.py-199):

```
firebird+fdb://SYSDBA:d66cbc9b@localhost/home/viktor/BDD/siteweb.fdb
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've tried with port and without but now I have another error : sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError) ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE: -902\n- I/O error during "open" operation for file "home/viktor/BDD/siteweb"\n- Error while trying to open file\n- No such file or directory', -902, 335544344). Can you help me one more time ? :)

Comment: Try adding an extra `/` before `home`. It is currently sending the path without an initial slash, so it is handled like a relative path by the server. Adding a slash will fix that.